# Wordpress parent template text remove

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a very new to wordpress. I have a very simple question however,
I can't fix by myself

here is my question:
I would like to remove a placeholder hint text in my website
I've checked google inspect tool on my site

and found the source code in here under includes/jobs/job-post-new-or-edit.php

```
   <input data-validate="package_price<?php echo $i; ?>" class="package_price" step="0.01" 
   name="package_price[]" type="number" placeholder="<?php echo __( 'Insert package price', 
   'wpjobster' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $pck_price_val ? $pck_price_val[$i] : ''; ?>">
```

I've messed around on google inspect and deleted

```
   placeholder="<?php echo __( 'Insert package price', 'wpjobster' ); ?>"
```

Then the placeholder hint text would be gone (result that I want).
However, I don't know how to do it right in my child theme.

I've done some research that I should probably add_filter in my child theme function.php
instead of remove in parent theme.

Could somebody please help with this.

Thanks a lot.

PS: I've found apply_filters in parent theme.

```
$package_required_fields = apply_filters( 
'wpj_job_package_required_fields_filter', array( 'package_name', 
'package_description' ,'package_price' ) );
```

the above placeholder is existing in 'package_price' does this mean I am able to add_filters in my child theme function to remove/blank the placeholder hint text.